# AppCompat v22: Reference new interpolators via XML

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I've been trying to take advantage of the new interpolators now available in v22 of the support library (FastOutLinearIn, etc).  More specifically, I'd like to reference them via XML.

I tried using @android:interpolator/fast_out_linear_in but LINT tells me that's the v21+ version.  I tried digging around elsewhere and found nothing that looked like it could help.

I also tried to create custom interpolators like this: (in *my_linear_out_slow_in.xml*)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<linearOutSlowInInterpolator />
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.animation.LinearOutSlowInInterpolator          
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

but they don't work in Lollipop or prior versions:  The activity transitions no longer appear, leaving the app in a state where the old activity is still visible but unresponsive because, I assume, the new activity is considered active but isn't being rendered.  Before the upgrade, when the v21+ styles used the new (non-compat) interpolators, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is impossible to use the design support library's interpolators in xml. This is because of how `AnimationUtils` handles creating an interpolator.

Taken from Gingerbread (API 9) source
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.2_r1/android/view/animation/AnimationUtils.java?av=f

```
 private static Interpolator createInterpolatorFromXml(Context c, XmlPullParser parser)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

    Interpolator interpolator = null;

    // Make sure we are on a start tag.
    int type;
    int depth = parser.getDepth();

    while (((type=parser.next()) != XmlPullParser.END_TAG || parser.getDepth() > depth)
           && type != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

        if (type != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }

        AttributeSet attrs = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);

        String  name = parser.getName();


        if (name.equals("linearInterpolator")) {
            interpolator = new LinearInterpolator(c, attrs);
        } else if (name.equals("accelerateInterpolator")) {
            interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator(c, attrs);
        } else if (name.equals("decelerateInterpolator")) {
            interpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator(c, attrs);
        }  else if (name.equals("accelerateDecelerateInterpolator")) {
            interpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator(c, attrs);
        }  else if (name.equals("cycleInterpolator")) {
            interpolator = new CycleInterpolator(c, attrs);
        } else if (name.equals("anticipateInterpolator")) {
            interpolator = new AnticipateInterpolator(c, attrs);
        } else if (name.equals("overshootInterpolator")) {
            interpolator = new OvershootInterpolator(c, attrs);
        } else if (name.equals("anticipateOvershootInterpolator")) {
            interpolator = new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator(c, attrs);
        } else if (name.equals("bounceInterpolator")) {
            interpolator = new BounceInterpolator(c, attrs);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown interpolator name: " + parser.getName());
        }

    }

    return interpolator;

}
```

They follow the same codepath but in lollipop a new Interpolator was added, `PathInterpolator`, which is the "base class" of all the new interpolators.

You can use the new interpolators, however they would need to be in a versioned resource directory for xml's. One work around would be to create your own "AnimationUtils" however that would mean including one more method + your R.anim.* whenever you find a method that accepts a id for an animation.